# Kotlin: Unchecked cast: Seal Class to it's Child Class (with generic). How to prevent that?

Tags: kotlin

I have `when` on a `seal class`, where I use to check if it is of certain class, I'll use the data. It has a generic `T` as seen below.

```
sealed class State
object Empty : State()
class Load<T>(val presentable: Presentable<T>) : State()
class Data<T>(val presentable: Presentable<T>) : State()

class LoadableContentController<T>(
        private val presenter: LoadableContentPresenter<T>) {

    private var state: State = Empty

    fun present(content: Presentable<T>?) {
        this.state = if (content == null) {
            Empty
        } else {
            Data(content)
        }
        this.performSideEffects()
    }

    private fun performSideEffects() {
        when (this.state) {
            is Data<*> -> {
                presenter.present((state as Data<T>).presentable)
            }
            is Load<*> -> {
                presenter.present((state as Load<T>).presentable)
            }
        }
    }
}

interface LoadableContentPresenter<T> {
    fun present(presentable: Presentable<T>)
}

interface Presentable<T> {
    val TAG: String
    fun createView(): () -> T
}
```

The code works. However it complaints `Unchecked cast: State to Load<T>` for the below.

```
presenter.present((state as Load<T>).presentable)
```

Is there a way to prevent the warning, or to have auto-casting happening (so I don't need to cast it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply make the base class generic:

```
sealed class State<out T>
object Empty : State<Nothing>()
class Load<T>(val presentable: Presentable<T>) : State<T>()
class Data<T>(val presentable: Presentable<T>) : State<T>()
```

And in your class:

```
class LoadableContentController<T>(
        private val presenter: LoadableContentPresenter<T>) {

    private var state: State<T> = Empty

    private fun performSideEffects() {
        val state = this.state
        when (state) {
            is Data<T> -> {
                presenter.present(state.presentable)
            }
            is Load<T> -> {
                presenter.present(state.presentable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got error at `is Data<T>` complaining `Cannot check for instance of erased type: Data<T>` :(

Comment: Ops, my bad... some type on the `State<T> = Empty` on my side. I use `State<out T> = Empty`... which cause the error

Comment: I have added more info to my question... I actually have another function `present`. With your answer above, I encounter error at `Data(content)`, expecting it to be `State<T>` and not `Data<T>`.

Comment: Again my bad, the `present` function should have `T` type for it. Fixing that clear the issue. Thanks so much. Great answer from you!!